# Toggling a server limited command

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

#f spam

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
         return
    elif message.content.lower() == 'f':
        await message.channel.send('f')
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

this is my current code for an f spam or sends an f each time a user does.
I was wanting to make this command **toggleable** and also **server/guild limited** if possible.
for example someone says `!fspam` and it gets toggled and switched off and when done the same again it gets turned on. OR it could be `!fspam on`/ `!fspam off`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Command.enable](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.enabled), where you can use [command.update](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Command.update) to. This will raise the DisabledCommand error.

Also please dont just copy and paste the code, try understanding what I did.This will disable it for all the guilds to. If you want it per server then you will need to use a database.

For example:

```
@client.command()
async def enable(ctx,*,command):
    command = client.get_command(command)
    command.update(enabled=True)
    await ctx.send(f"{command} enabled!")

@client.command()
async def disable(ctx,*,command):
    command = client.get_command(command)
    command.update(enabled=False)
    await ctx.send(f"{command} disabled!")
```

Comment: This is gonna disable the command for all guilds, OP wants to make it guild independent.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński hm, then he will need to use a database.

Comment: no no thisi is what i was looking for , guild independant OR toggleable. 
and yes i did understand what youve done, thanks alot!